# Setting Boolean Values in Java Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

Here is my very, very trimmed down version including only the boolean values and the structure around it:

```
public int payoffDebt(Double totalDebt) {

    boolean booIsPaid[] = new boolean[c.getCount()];
    int bb = 0; 
    int bbb = 0;


    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        booIsPaid[bb++] = false;
    }

    while (totalDebt > 0) {

        for (int i : rowCounter) { 

            if ((indBal[p] <= 0) && (booIsPaid[bbb] == false)) {
                booIsPaid[bbb++] = true;
            } 


        }

    }
    return monthTotal;
}
```

This is what I am trying to do, early on I loop through user "debts" and assign a Boolean value to each one called booIsPaid.  They are set to false and this works fine.  However, down below, I don't think I am iterating through them correctly because in my Android Application I get Window Leaking LogCat's in my Activity where this is called.  I comment out where I set it to `true` and all runs fine.  Can someone see where it is not right?

**Edit:  Stacktrace:**

```
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at com.---.---.DebtDataSource.payoffDebt(DebtDataSource.java:290)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at com.---.---.Planner$PlannerTask.doInBackground(Planner.java:73)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at com.---.---.Planner$PlannerTask.doInBackground(Planner.java:1)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
12-02 21:14:35.121: E/AndroidRuntime(8832):     ... 5 more
12-02 21:14:35.128: W/ActivityManager(291):   Force finishing activity com.---.---/.Planner
12-02 21:14:35.175: W/ActivityManager(291):   Force finishing activity com.---.---/.ManageDebts
12-02 21:14:35.285: W/ActivityManager(291): Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{41e0b390 com.---.---/.Planner}
12-02 21:14:35.496: I/ActivityManager(291): Displayed com.---.---/.Planner: +557ms
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832): Activity com.---.---.Planner has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4175e930 that was originally added here
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.---.---.Planner has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4175e930 that was originally added here
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:374)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:292)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:224)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:547)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at com.---.---.Planner$PlannerTask.onPreExecute(Planner.java:56)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at com.---.---.Planner.onCreate(Planner.java:36)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-02 21:14:35.605: E/WindowManager(8832):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:
I have reworked everything, here is my new method:**

```
while (totalDebt > 0) {

booIsPaid = false;
remainingBalance = 0;

// Increment month
monthTotal = monthTotal + 1;

// update INDIVIDUAL debt Here
for (int i : rowCounter) { 

nameList.add(indName[r++]);

// Zero Balance, set Boolean true, add to Remainder     
if ((indBal[p] <= 0) && !booIsPaid) { 
        booIsPaid = true;
        remainingbalance = remainingbalance + indPay[q];
        indPay[q] = 0;
        indBal[p] = 0;
        payList.add(Double.valueOf(IndPay));
    // First balance after zero; set Boolean false, add to remainder to payment.
    } else if  ((indBal[p] > 0) && booIsPaid) { 
       booIsPaid = false;       
       indPay[q] = indPay[q] + remainingbalance;
        indPay[q] = Math.round(indPay[q] * 100.00) / 100.00;
        IndPay = myFormat.format(indPay[q]);
        payList.add(Double.valueOf(IndPay));

 // Other remaining balances
    } else if  ((indBal[p] > 0) && !booIsPaid) {        indPay[q] = 0;
        indPay[q] = Math.round(indPay[q] * 100.00) / 100.00;
        IndPay = myFormat.format(indPay[q]);
        payList.add(Double.valueOf(IndPay));
    }

// indPay[q] (should or should not include remainder here!
    indBal[p] = indBal[p] - (indPay[q] - interestFee);
    totalDebt = totalDebt - (indPay[q++] - interestFee);

    IndBal = myFormat.format(indBal[p++]);
    indBalList.add(Double.valueOf(IndBal));
    feeList.add(Double.valueOf(InterestFee));
}
}
```

Note:  The output is being stored in the four ArrayLists here which will be printed out to the user on a month by month basis.

The whole practical application is too come up with a debt-payoff strategy.  I have yet to test this and will report back.  Any feedback? let me know!

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: are you decrementing the `totalDebt` somewhere?

Comment: Is it IndexOutOfBounds exception?

Comment: I have added Stacktrace/LogCat

Comment: @cacho, yes, I edit all of that out.

Comment: Where does `rowCounter` come from?  What's it set to initially?  Actually, where do each variable that doesn't appear to be declared in that method come from?

Comment: @Makoto Sorry, I haven't had time with this.  Will test this evening. Each variable is defined in the method, except the ArrayLists which are class variables (fields).  I am thinking a better way to do this is not use a Boolean Array, just a single Boolean is all I need that will reset itself on each loop.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=4; index=4
at com.---.---.DebtDataSource.payoffDebt(DebtDataSource.java:290)
```

You are trying to access an index out of the bounds of your array. Check out the [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) documentation.

Can you post this specific line code:

```
DebtDataSource.payoffDebt(DebtDataSource.java:290)
```

You need to check if the variable `bbb` is inside the bounds of your array. I think that is the problem, try changing your code to this:

```
if ((indBal[p] <= 0) && (booIsPaid[bbb] == false) && (bbb <= booIsPaid.length)){
      booIsPaid[bbb++] = true;
}
```

I will also suggest that you re-set the value of `bbb` to zero at some point of your loop code.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

Some issue/observations below:

1. There is no need of first loop as `boolean []` is already initialized with values as `false`
2. There is no need for `boolean` comparison with `false`, as you can simply write `if ((indBal[p] <= 0) && !booIsPaid[bbb]) {`
3. There is no check on the array length(**that is causing your issue**) in your while loop. Add that as below:

   ```
   while (totalDebt > 0 && bbb <booIsPaid.length) {
     for (int i : rowCounter) { 
       if (indBal[p] <= 0 && !booIsPaid[bbb]  &&  bbb <booIsPaid.length) {
           booIsPaid[bbb++] = true;
       } 
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I reworked my method that I am using to not include arrays, but only a single "toggle" Boolean.  I used your #2 point. Thanks for that, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't have to set each value in the boolean array to `false`.  They're set by default that way.

Second, your loop does look a bit suspect.  The following would resolve the AIOOBException you're getting.

```
while (totalDebt > 0) {
    for (int i : rowCounter) { 
        if (indBal[p] <= 0 && !booIsPaid[bbb]) {
            booIsPaid[bbb++] = true;
        } 
    }
    bbb = 0;
}
return monthTotal;
```

The reason:  `bbb` grows without bound while you're iterating in the `while` and `for`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have actually decided to go to a different route.  I added all my code up top.  I have to test.  Will report back.